# Block access to the Clash Royale by the Wi-Fi router

Tags: ip, firewall, modem, blocking

Modem model [Technicolor TD5336]

[image]

According to information from the Ubiquiti Networks forum the port is **9339**.

URL: **game.clashroyaleapp.com** https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265516/what-are-the-ip-adresses-of-the-clash-royale-servers

Some screens of the modem settings management interface can be seen here:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx2ZWxveHZ2YXxneDo0ZjEwMjg3ZGJmMDFkOTc2

**[Edit]**:

Configuration tree:

```
    SETUP
        Internet Setup
        3G Setup
        Ethernet WAN
        Wireless Setting
        Local Network
        Time and Date
    ADVANCED
        Advanced Wireless
        Multi-WAN
        Advanced-LAN
        IPv6 WAN
        IPv6 LAN
        DSL Settings
        RIP Settings
        NAT
        Firewall
        Static Route
        Multicast
        Dynamic DNS
        DNS Route
        Port Mapping
        Quality of Service
        UPnP
        SNMP
    SHARE
        Samba
        Share Management
        Disk Management
        Printer Server
    MAINTENANCE
        Password
        User Configuration
        Remote Manage
        Remote Access
        SysLog
        Time Schedule
        Firmware Upgrade
        Backup/Restore
        Ping
        Diagnostic
        Reboot Device
    STATUS
        Summary
        IPv6 Info
        xDSL Info
        Wireless Clients
        LAN Clients
        Logs
        Routing Table
        Driver Version
        Statistics
```

Comment: Closed-source modems/routers like this  are famous for keeping bugs as backdoors that are used by your ISP and governmental (US and other) mass surveillance services. To keep your local area network private, I recommend you plug your devices into a router you bought and install a regularly updated open-source firmware on it. Your WiFi access point should also be served by that open-source router. The only device connected to this TD5336 should be your router. Firmwares like openwrt.org give you more features and more freedom configuring your network.

Answer (score 5):

The firewalls on consumer routers are not *that* great - especially on ISP supplied systems like this one.

The "best" way to block this is at the DNS server - something like opendns would be an easy way to do it, but it looks like your router dosen't support it.

While its a bit of work, the 'right' way to do this feels like using the firewall.

Lets start by identifying the IP addresses that resolve to `game.clashroyaleapp.com`

On windows, the command is nslookup. On everything else that's dig

```
C:\Users\faile_000>nslookup game.clashroyaleapp.com
Server:  router.asus.com
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    game.clashroyaleapp.com
Addresses:  54.213.222.145
          54.191.58.77
          54.213.222.129
          54.191.202.192
          54.191.120.112
```

Now we need to block these. It makes sense to block these rather than the ports since the application seems to use a large range of ports.

Essentially you need to create one rule per IP address (and periodically update it as they add servers). Unfortunately, without the router on hand, I can only guess that essentially, you need to create rules with these addresses as the source address with the interface being set to *any*. You'd want to set action as *deny*.

Of course, test this, and adjust as needed.

Comment: Hey @JounerymanGeek, would you like to continue this discussion via chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54952/block-access-to-the-clash-royale-by-the-wi-fi-router

Answer (score 3):

> From [Source](http://setuprouter.com/router/technicolor/td5130/manual-1247.pdf) (Page 30):

The Parental Control page allows you to filter web sites that a network device may access or be denied
access.
To view the Parental Control page, do one of the following:

- From the Home screen, click Parental Control under Toolbox.
- On the main menu, click Toolbox > Parental Control.

[image: screenshot1]

To configure parental control, click Configure on the upper-right corner of the screen.

[image]

- Use Address Based Filter — Check to filter web sites by address.
- Actionfor Unknown Sites — Select whether to Block or Allow unknown
  sites.
- Click Apply to save changes.
- Web Site — Enter the URL of the web site to block or allow.
- Action — Select one of the following options:
- Block: To block the web site.
- Allow: To allow access to the web site.
- Redirect: To redirect to another web site if the web site defined on
  the Web Site field is being accessed.
- Redirect — If Redirect is selected in Action, enter the URL address
  to where you want to redirect the site.
- Click Add to save the changes to the table.

---

If you want to, you can also add an exception to the firewall.
I do not have this Router model so I cannot help you completely, but in

> ADVANCED > Firewall > URL Filter

Add the URL you want to block and be sure you are Blocking it, not allowing it.

If you want some further help, please post a screenshot of this menu.

Comment: Hello @Darksoulpk68, take a look at the issue. The model TD5336 does not have **Parental Control**.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hello again @Darksoulpk68, i need the **FQDN** (Fully Qualified Domain Name). Any idea (for a URL mentioned in question)?

Comment: A FQDN ends with a period. However, if the feature name is “URL Filter”, I very much doubt it will block anything but unencrypted HTTP, on port 80.

Comment: *typically* answers shouldn't be lifted directly off of external sources - it might be worth paraphrasing the essential bits instead. While you rewrite the answer, also consider that the firewall rules and blocking the *port* might be a suitable alternative.